# Enabling and Disabling children in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to create an enable/ disable game objects in Unity.  I used [GameObject.SetActiveRecursively](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActiveRecursively.html) but it only works one-way.

I used a collider in which when an object enters the collider.  The game objects become enabled.  When they leave or get to a certain point, they disable.

How would I make this a two way system, making it able to be enabled while inside the collider and disabled when outside the collider?

-- The collider is in the game object who is being disabled and enabled.

According to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14014/activate-children.html) information from Unity Answers, the object becomes disabled.  So how would I make the object enabled?

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(true);

    }
}

function OnTriggerExit(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html

Comment: @Rubber Mallet Yes, that's how I formatted the script.  But when I return to where the collider is (after I have exited), the game object doesn't return.  I'm thinking to put the collider into a different object can use the script to call the other object. But I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Can you post a bit of the code you're using to help get a better picture of what you're trying.  Sounds like you have a trigger, an object that you want to dis/enable, and a player that walks into and out of the trigger to affect the other object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the following hierarchy:

- ColliderAndScript

  - SetOfMeshes
  - AnotherSetOfMeshes

Attach your script and collider to ColliderAndScript. Add your things you want enabled/disabled as children. Then make your script like this:

```
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        for (var child : Transform in transform) {
            child.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(false);
        }
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        for (var child : Transform in transform) {
            child.gameObject.SetActiveRecursively(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This should enable all children when you enter the collider, and disable them when you exit.

Answer (score 2):

If the collider is on an inactive game object, then of course it will never trigger, because it's not even in the game any more.

For something like this, the collider needs to be on a different object to the one you are switching on and off. Have the script on the collider object look up that other object to call SetActiveRecursively on it in both cases.

Comment: How would I do that?  I don't know how to call other game objects(children) in the Heiarchy but only in prefabs from the project files.  From what you are saying, I would have to create a parent object and a child object, and put the script in the parent while the child object is being turned on and off.  Inside the script I would have to call the children and make set"SetActiveRecursively" to the child object.  But as I said before, I don't know how to call the children of the a game object.  Can you give me an example on how it is done?

Comment: This sort of thing is detailed in the Unity docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

Comment: I saw that but I don't understand it that well because I'm not using a script.  I'm just turning on and off the child object

Comment: The code that does the "turning off" is in a script!

Comment: yes, but not the turn on

Comment: You can't do anything at runtime in Unity without it being in a script. The example you give above is in a script. It will need to be in a script, just not on a disabled object. So it's not clear what your problem is.